# How to "Exclude from Project" in VS2015 from Package Manager Console(i.e. Script)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-shell

I can right click a file and "Exclude From Project"

In Package Manager Console or script, I can delete the file. <- But the file shows as missing as opposed to having been excluded from the project.

Is the only solution to manually edit the Project File and Reload the project?

[image]